# A probability question of seperating people to different teams

Tags: probability

There are 20 people in a room, one of them called John and another one called Steve.

We are seperating the group of people into two 10 sized group to play a game against each other in teams.

Whats the probability of John is going to play against Steve? (So John and Steve are in different teams) And Why?

I tried this way:

We separate John, so there will be 19 other people in the other side of the room.
18 of 19 could be "good" selection for John's team because the nineteenth person is Steve.

So we could select 9 person (to be complete 10 people group) of 18 people.

[image]

And im stuck here. (But this is could be terribly wrong, i just started to learn these things.)

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem? If so, where did you stuck at?

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the $19$ people who are not John, $9$ of them will be on John's team, and $10$ of them will be on the opposing team.  Therefore anyone (other than John), including Steve, has $\frac{10}{19}$ probability of being on the team opposing John's team.

Comment: Yes this is it, Thanks for the description!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi note that while this is elegant and much simpler than the path you started down, you had found $\binom{18}{9}$ ways to fill John's team without Steve. But as there are a total of $\binom{19}{9}$ ways to fill John's team from all players including Steve, the probability that Steve is not on John's team is $\binom{18}{9}/\binom{19}{9} = \frac{10}{19}.$

Comment: Good to hear i was in a good path!